# TS2339:Propert 'on' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly

I'm using plotly code in angular 2. I'm getting error for following code. I referred [this code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544875/how-to-expand-only-x-axis-of-plotly-area-graph-on-drag)

My code is:

```
var plotDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
    function(eventdata){
      alert( 'ZOOM!' + '\n\n' +
        'Event data:' + '\n' +
        JSON.stringify(eventdata) + '\n\n' +
        'x-axis start:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])+ '\n' +
        'x-axis end:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']));
      var xVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
      var yVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
    }
  );
```

I'm getting error for plotDiv.on('....') function. Is there any alternate function for .on() in angular 2?
Please help me. I stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried `var plotDiv: any = ...`?

Comment: `.on()` is a method of jQuery

Comment: HTMLElements indeed do not have an `.on` method. Perhaps you want to wrap it in a jQuery wrapper?: `$(plotDiv).on(....)`

Comment: @yurzui, Thank you so much. var plotDiv: any = ...? This is your solution is working fine for me.

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JLRishe, Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JLRishe Your solution works, but I just wonder if there's a way to deal with it without using `jQuery`. Looking forward for your full answer.

Comment: @Kinduser It should work withour using jQuery

Comment: @Kinduser I stand corrected. It looks like Plotly adds an `.on` method to elements when a plot is added to them. If you are using plain JS, I think you can just use this method. If you're using Typescript, see yurzui's answer.

Comment: @Kinduser, I'm using Typescript and yurzui answer working fine for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To prevent this error you can write:

```
var plotDiv: any = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout', ...
```

`document.getElementById('myDiv')` return `HTMLElement`. This type doesn't contain method `on` because this method is added within `plotly-latest.min.js`. So in order to silence the typescript warning you can explicity say compile not to check types for `plotDiv`

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aB5Z7KXZ6MWx8Sn4FBYM?p=preview)**

Another way is create type definition like:

```
interface PlotHTMLElement extends HTMLElement  {
  on(eventName: string, handler: Function): void;
}

var plotDiv  = <PlotHTMLElement>document.getElementById('myDiv')
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout', function() {

});
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but I would suggest adding some explanation as to why this remedies the issue (especially since there's a bounty on this question).

Comment: Is it the best solution possible? Are there any contraindications to use the `any` keyword?

Comment: @Kinduser This is the simplest solution. You can create your own type definition file if you want. The main disadvantage of writing `any` is lack of autocomplete in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach is to use string literal parameter types to declare a specialized return type for DOM selector functions. Then we define properties and events that are specific to the these elements.

This is possible thanks to TypeScript's open ended interfaces.

```
// Assuming you using modules as you mention Angular 2
// if this is actually script code and not a module, remove the `declare global` wrapper

declare global {
  interface Document {
    // This only enhances the return type of getElementById for the exact selector "myDiv".
    getElementById("myDiv"): HTMLDivElement & {
      // intersection `&` is used to add the specialized event.
      on('plotly_relayout', (eventdata: {/* fill this in as needed */}) => void);
    };
  }
}
```

With this declaration, your original core will typecheck. There is no need to introduce type assertions and we are able to maintain a more declarative style. Furthermore, this serves as documentation of our *expectations* of the div myDiv, at the API level.

**EDIT:**

It appears you may be using jQuery, if so, the approach is the same and the code almost identical.

```
declare global {
  interface JQueryStatic {
    ("#myDiv"): JQuery & {
      on('plotly_relayout', (eventdata: {/* fill this in as needed */}) => void);
    };
  }
}
```